# NAT Gateway IP for k8s cluster not reflected in pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I tried to create a NAT gateway as mentioned in the given tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine
After applying the terraform, though the NAT Gateway is created and assigned an IP, any outgoing traffic from the pods still comes as the Node's IP rather than the NAT Gateway's IP. Couldn't find any troubleshooting guide for the same. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to ensrure you GKE cluster is private since by now it only works using [Kubernetes “private” clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters). If the VM instances have an external IP, the routing will be through them and not by Cloud NAT.

Comment: I couldn't see any references where NAT Gateway is applicable only for private clusters. Can you point to any related reference docs?

Comment: Yes, you’re right it’s not referenced to any documentation, however I’ve performed a lot of tests and the reason of why Cloud NAT doesn’t work with non-private kubernetes cluster is due to right now pod’s IP gets SNAT’d to node’s private IP for internet access, and if this is not private kubernetes cluster, node will have an external IP assigned to it. So, in this case you will see internet bound packets with the node’s external IP, and *not* with the cloud NAT IP.

Comment: The first sentence of the [link](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) refers to Cloud NAT allows GCP VM instances and GKE clusters to connect to the Internet *if they don't have external, public IP addresses*. It’s not clear about the GKE private clusters but it mentions about the external IP addresses.

Comment: I noticed the doc has been updated which mentions:

[Regular (non-private) GKE clusters assign each node an external IP address, so such clusters cannot use Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#nat-not-performed) to send packets from the node's primary interface.